# How do I make a constructor (module.exports) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on making an npm module and it keeps responding with a "`is not a constructor error`". Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = function () {
    this.Client = function () {
        new Discord.Client()
    }

    this.Client.whenEvent = function (event, callback) {
        const client = this.Client();
     client.on(event, callback)
    }


    this.Client.login = function (token) {
        const client = this.Client()
        client.login(token)
    }
}
```

and here is my testing code if you need it as well

```js
const diss = require('./index.js')
const client = new diss.Client()

client.whenEvent('ready', () => {
    console.log('IM READY!')
})

client.whenEvent('message', message => {
    if (message.content == "test") {
        message.channel.send('diss.js worked! NOW ADD STUFF!')
    }
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied that error message correctly? I've never seen that one before but I have seen _"is not a constructor"_

Comment: Sorry @Phil I updated it so people wouldn't be confused :)

Comment: I suggest you make your module a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and export that if you intend to use it as one

Comment: `diss.Client` won't work until you have a `new diss()`. Plus that method has no `return`

Comment: I already tried that @charlietfl and it didnt work. Can you please show a code example